# python3 error __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]

Tags: python-3.x

```
     session['filenames']= session['filenames'] + filename+","
  File "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 368, in <lambda>
    __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]
KeyError: 'filenames'
```

I am storing the name of files in this session variable and i am getting this error. Can someone please explain why or help.
[Full code here](http://pastebin.com/93vUSH2Z)

my upload script first goes to /upload/image/start

so and i can see that in logs so it mus be getting set?

[upload script](http://pastebin.com/Z0L3Rzkb)

Comment: It looks like the session dict does not have a `'filenames'` key.

Comment: it does though i have set it previously, i will put the rest of my code on @TamasHegedus

Comment: That would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the session dict does not have a `"filenames"` entry at first.
Try changing that line to:

```
session['filenames'] = session.get('filenames', '') + filename + ","
```